# Digest authentication using Request v2.88.0 in node.js

Tags: node.js, digest-authentication

When I tried to access with the digest authentication with the following code, I am getting the unauthorized error. But when I tried to make the request on Postman, it was working well.

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: this._uri,
    auth: {
        user: 'vv',
        pass: 'pass',
        sendImmediately: false
    }
    body: {
        method: procedureName, 
        params: postParams, 
        id: 'jsonrpc',
    },
    json: true
};
request(
    options,
    function (error, response, body) {
        // body is the decompressed response body

    }
);
```

Comment: Try [running `request` in debug mode](https://github.com/request/request#debugging) to see what's going on.

Comment: Hi @robertkelp, Here is the [debug result.](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3072#issuecomment-442120402)

Comment: Please remove your credentials from that file!

Comment: @robertklep, sorry what do you mean? you mean my credentials for sumokoin? if yes, don't need it, because it is an empty one for testing :)

Comment: Ah okay :D I meant those, yes, I thought they might have been from a real account.

Comment: @robertklep, did you got any reason?

Comment: No sorry, it looks like `request` is making an authenticated request, but it fails. Perhaps either the server or `request` are using a non-standard form, but I don't know enough about HTTP Digest to say which side is wrong.